# Button Tag Property

Tags: c#

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if (c is Button)
   {
      Button b = (Button)c;
      if (b.Tag.Equals("submit") && b.Tag.Equals("save"))
      {
         b.Visible = false;
      }
   }
}
```

I m trying to hide these to tag property button other will be show on form load here is my code its not working. but error show "Object Reference not set an............"

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is a really bad formatted question. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: tag is an object not a string -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx - Is there a tag value? (or tostring)

Comment: How can `b.Tag` equal **both** `"submit"` and `"save"` at the same time?

Comment: do you even get some Button's? and does there `Tag`property contains your Values?

Comment: yup i get button in b by foreach

Comment: @p.s.w.g it should be `||` "Or" right?

Comment: @GeneralDunblade I would presume so, but given the question's text it's hard to tell what's actually being asked.

Comment: I think he's trying to hide button that is "submit" and "save"

Comment: button is not hide i will hide these button

Answer (score 6):

Question 1: Did you actually set `Tag` to anything?
Question 2: Why use the `Tag` and not the button instance itself?
Question 3: How is the `Tag` supposed to be one value and another value at the same time?

On question 2): you could do this

```
if (c == btnSubmit) { ... }
if (c == btnSave) { ... }
```

given that you named the two buttons in the properties. **This is also the solution I'd recommend!**

On question 3): your code should (*probably*) read

```
if (b.Tag.ToString().Equals("submit") || b.Tag.ToString().Equals("save"))
{
   b.Visible = false;
}
```

---

It just struck me that your entire code can be refactured to the following, assuming that the buttons are named accordingly:

```
btnSubmit.Visible = false;
btnSave.Visible = false;
```

No loop, no nothing! Every control on your form by default has an instance member in the class, too (unless you configure it otherwise in the control's properties). So why would you loop over all controls on the form (which, by the way, wouldn't even work if the buttons were inside a `Panel`) just to find two buttons you want to hide when you could "call them by their name" in the first place?

Comment: Your right, but im not convinced tag will equal either string as I mentioned in my comment (not answer as Im not able to test) +1

Comment: Could be ;-) I'm making a minor change to make it work... However, if I was the OP, I wouldn't use the `Tag` anyway...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar you don't need `.ToString().Equals("submit")` you can just do `.ToString() == "submit"` but you should probably make sure `.Tag` is not null before anything else.

Comment: For the first solution, you can just use `btnSubmit.Visible = false;`, `btnSave.Visible = false;`, no need to look through the controls on the form

Comment: @Darkzaelus: Hahaha, I didn't really look at what his code is doing, but you're entirely right! All this ado to just hide to buttons... ;-)

Comment: @p.s.w.g While you're right that there's no practical difference between `Equals` and `==` *for strings*, there's a big difference for other object types and as I'm lazy, I don't want to think hard all the time, so I always use `Equals`... ;-)

Comment: this not work error shown "object reference not set............"

Comment: Makes things easier :) it took me 3 thought iterations to get to that point, at least it's close to friday

Comment: @user2261536 There you go. Tags are not set in the properties. *I advise you to read my answer again and change your code accordingly (see Question 2 and addendum)*

Comment: im set button1 tag property "submit" and btn2 tag property "save" but its not working

Comment: **Do not use the `Tag`!! Use your instance members correctly!!** Name your controls (in Property-editor, change the value of `Name` property) and then in your code, delete the loop and instead write `<name>.Visible = false`, where `<name>` is what you wrote for the `Name` property of the button!

Comment: If you already know the button is named `button1`, you can simply write `button1.Visible = false` in your code! *Remove the loop!*

Comment: m access form control from my class :@ n i have 15 forms so means 2*15=30 buttons i will hide on runtime

Comment: I highly doubt you have 15 forms open at once, and if you do then theres probably something wrong there.. just set them visible and invisible when you open a form. Or look into how you can databind visibilty to a method **Edit** even if your 15 forms are all open this wouldnt work because it only loops through one forms controls